# The name "Word" is not a class/type

Tags: list, class, dart

I have three classes in Dart, shown below:

Bit:

```dart
part of CB_Crypto;

class Bit {
  bool _state = false,
       _sympathetic = false;
  int _alignment = 0;

  Bit(List args) {
    _state = args[0];
    _sympathetic = args[1];
    _alignment = args[2];
  }

  bool state() => _state;

  bool not() => _state = !_state;

  bool set(bool state) => _state = state;

  bool isSympathetic() =>  _sympathetic;

  operator &(Bit b) => state() && b.state();

  operator |(Bit b) => state() || b.state();
}
```

Word:

```dart
part of CB_Crypto;

class Word {
  List<Bit> _bits = [];

  Word(List<List> bits) {
    bits.forEach((bit) => _bits.add(new Bit(bit)));
  }

  bool not(int i) => _bits[i].not();

  void notAll() => _bits.forEach((bit) => bit.not());

}
```

Table:

```dart
part of CB_Crypto;

class Table {
  List<Word> _words;

  Word(List<List> words) {
    words.forEach((word) => _words.add(new Word(word)));
  }
}
```

These are all in different files and are part of the same library. However I'm getting a warning from Dartium in the Table class for using Word as a type and trying to instantiate a Word object: `the name "Word" is not a (type/class) and cannot be used as a parametrized  type`.

I believe I wrote the Word class similar to the Bit class, and that does not throw an error when used in Table as Word is used. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show the code that raises this error, please?

Comment: I am wondering that this works:

`Word(List<List> words) {` - For a better understanding you should type the (inner) list for us.

Comment: Did you add `part "file.dart"` for each part to your library?

Comment: @Robert the code that throws the error is the Table class (List definition and the forEach loop.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes i did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Word as a Constructor within the Table class.

```
Word(List<List> words) {
  words.forEach((word) => _words.add(new Word(word)));
}
```

Your constructor should be a `Table` from the looks of it.

```
Table(List<List> words) {
  words.forEach((word) => _words.add(new Word(word)));
}
```

Comment: I can't believe i didnt notice that. I did copy and past Table's code from Word and changed all the names because they were essentially the same. I guess I missed one :) thanks